# access the outer div using an element inside it

Tags: jquery

```
<div class='container'>
  <a href="#">Click</a>
</div>
```

How can I access the outer div using the anchor as a starting point in jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Let `this` be your anchor, you can use:

```
$(this).closest("div")
```

Comment: what will this do if there is a div directly below the a tag? or above it... as in a sibling element, wont this break?

Comment: @samccone: No, it won't. http://api.jquery.com/closest/ "Get the first *ancestor* element that matches the selector, *beginning at the current element and progressing up* through the DOM tree."

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.parent();` alone for direct parent, or `.parent('.container');` to search way up for a match

Example:

```
$('a').bind('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().css('background-color','red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`parent()` jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
$(".container a").click(function() {
    // do something with the parent div here
    var div = $(this).parent();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('a').click(function(){$(this).parent().hide();});`

this will grab the parent of the a tag and then hide it as an example the parent() function is what you want to use for this